# Redirect to url from "post-only" view

Tags: django, url, redirect

I have the following setup for a combination of a DetailView and a FormView:

```
class EventBookView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = EventBookBaseView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = EventBookFormView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

class EventBookBaseView(DetailView):
    template_name = "event_book.html"
    model= Event
    context_object_name = 'event'

class EventBookFormView(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "event_book.html"
    form_class = PersonalInfoForm
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'event'

    def post(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        #do stuff
        ...
        return redirect('user_bookings')
```

Unfortunately, the redirect to the url with the name 'user_bookings' is not working. How can I redirect to that url?

thanks!

Comment: `return redirect('user_bookings')` should work. You haven't really said what "isn't working", and you haven't shown any code in the `post` method so we can't tell what's going on there. Trying to include one post view in another using `EventBookFormView.as_view()` is a bit odd, I would avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [success_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url), when Form is properly processed then view is redirected.

eg.

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_bookings')
```

EDIT: changed reverse to reverse_lazy

Comment: how to fire it? I am using two forms on the same page, that are validated. after successful validation, I want to redirect, but I do not know how

Comment: I would rather create custom form rather than 2 forms on one page

Comment: I got a booking form for the quantity, a payment form and a personalinformation form. The thing is, that I do not need all of them at all times. If an event is free, there is no need of payment details. I am combining the two/three forms in one form tag with crispy forms.

Comment: So you need to use formset (plus FormSetView from django-extra-views) or  use TemplateView + process all forms + return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(view_name))

Answer (score -1):

A POST method should not return a redirection.
If you need so, try to use HttpResponseRedirect.

Like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_bookings/')
```

Comment: That is not working. What I want to do is redirecting the user after successfully submitting the form. basically thats what the success_url option in FormView is for, but I do not know how to fire it.